# Use of standard error of the mean when the components are not identically-distributed

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, central-limit-theorem

Let {$X_1$, ..., $X_n$} be a random sample of size n in which the different elements are measurements drawn from $m$ different populations with different distributions. From the Central Limit Theorem, as long as $n \gg m$ and $n  \to \infty$, the values of $\bar{X}$ obtained by repeating this experiment will follow a normal distribution irrespective of the properties of the different $m$ starting distributions.

Does this mean that it is valid to use the standard error of the mean as representative of the uncertainty on the $\bar{X}$? The different $\bar{X}$ are not independent measurements of the same variable, but the fact they they follow a normal distribution would make me believe it might be legitimate to do so.

Comment: "***irrespective*** *of the properties of the different m starting distributions*" is inaccurate. While it holds for a wide variety of situations, several properties must hold for the CLT to work. The standard error of a mean doesn't rely on the CLT at all; you simply use properties of variances.

Comment: @Glen_b Could you please explain what are these properties? From what I read it was really independent of the underlying distributions, but then I misunderstood. 
In any case, should I understand from your answer that the standard error of the mean can be used in this case?

Comment: I'll write an answer. Are the $X_i$ independent?

Comment: We can assume they are, but I would like to know how that assumptions impacts on the answer (if it is not too much work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we need are basic properties of [expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties) and [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties).

Let $X_i\sim F_i$ be independent with mean and variance $\mu_i$ and $\sigma^2_i$ respectively.

Then $E(\bar X)=\bar \mu = \frac{_1}{^n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i$ (linearity of expectation)

and $\text{Var}(\bar X) = \text{Var}(\frac{_1}{^n} \sum_{i=1}^nX_i) =\frac{_1}{^{n^2}} \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i)=\frac{_1}{^{n^2}} \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^2_i$.

From that, you can immediately compute the standard error of the mean as $\frac{1}{^n}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^2_i}$.

(Indeed, you don't have to have independence, uncorrelated variables will do.)

If the $X_i$ are correlated, the calculation can still be done (as long as you also know the pairwise covariances or correlations), it's just a little more complicated - 
specifically, $\text{Var}(\sum X_i) = \sum \text{Var}(X_i) + 2\sum\sum_{i< j} \text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$ -- which is again straight from basic properties of variance.

These are not asymptotic results, as the CLT is, but exact, finite sample results that hold whether you have normal distributions or not. For example, if $X_1$ is $\text{Exponential}(1)$ and $X_2$ is $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$, independent of $X_1$, their average is *not even close* to normal, but the standard error of their average is still given by the formula I gave above.

Here's a  histogram of simulated values and theoretical density for the average of a standard exponential and standard uniform:

[image]

$E(X_1)=1$ and $E(X_2)=\frac{1}{2}$. $E(\frac{X_1+X_2}{2})  = \frac{1+\frac{1}{2}}{2} = \frac{3}{4}$ (simulated = 0.74975).

$\text{Var}(X_1)=1$ and $\text{Var}(X_2)=\frac{1}{12}$. $\text{Var}(\frac{X_1+X_2}{2})  = \frac{1}{4} (1+\frac{1}{12}) = \frac{13}{48}=0.27083...$ (simulated = 0.273).

Standard error of the mean is then $\sqrt\frac{13}{48}\approx 0.5204$.

---

> Does this mean it is valid to use the standard error of the mean as representative of the uncertainty on the $\bar X$

That depends on what you regard as 'representative of the uncertainty'. There may be situations when you don't regard the standard error of $\bar X$ as the most appropriate way to measure the uncertainty of $\bar X$. If you want the standard error, you have it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Do I interpret correctly that the existence of $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i^2$ stem from the application of the CLT, or can we assume that all distributions have such quantities associated? I apologize if the question is getting too abstract, but I am really interested in getting to the limitations of this reasoning.

Comment: You cannot assume that all distributions have a finite mean and variance (there are obvious exceptions, like the Cauchy). The result - which relies on the mean and variance of the components - only applies to component-distributions whose mean and variance exist. Do I really need to say again that this is NOT to do with applying the CLT? The result is finite sample, so it *cannot* be about the CLT, which is only asymptotic and is about convergence to normality. Please get all thought of CLT out of your head when considering this question.